# Firebase rest auth - Cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to authenticate users with firebase cloud functions and REST api, instead of lets say, node + REST?

Comment: Yes, Its possibile.

Comment: How do i go on about doing this? Do i change something under /Users/[user] then make the cloud functions trigger on that, then send a post request?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What does *using cloud based functions* mean in this use case. i.e. Firebase has a full authentication system already - what do you need beyond that?

Comment: I know firebase has a working authentication, but I want it to perform faster and I think doing the authentication with rest will speed up the process. I want to use cloud functions to do the post request, if possible, so i remain serverless

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Firebase has built in functions to authenticate users. You can use OAuth or email-password based authentication.

Read the docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth)